# Issue with missing forward declaration in C++

Tags: c++, c, forward-declaration, function-prototypes

I have compiled following program without forward declaring function in `C`. It's successfully compiled and run in `GCC` without any warning or error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int ret = func(10, 5);
}

int func(int i, int j)
{
        return (i+j);
}
```

But, I have compiled following program without forward declaring function in `C++`, Compiler gives me an error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        int ret = func(10, 5);
}

int func(int i, int j)
{
        return (i+j);
}
```

**An Error:**

```
fl.cpp:6:22: error: ‘func’ was not declared in this scope
  int ret = func(10, 5);
                      ^
```

**Why C++ Compiler Gives an Error? Is it not by default take int data type?**

Comment: Never in C++, and no longer in C since 99

Comment: *"Why C++ Compiler Gives an Error?"* As usual: Because the standard says so.

Comment: @CraigYoung read it as "no fwd decl..."

Comment: Is the question title just a **complaint** about the fact that C++ requires declarations before functions are used and therefore in some cases needs "forward declarations"?

Comment: @CraigYoung Well, take it with a grain of salt. This question originates from the lack of knowledge that C and C++ are two different languages and should be treated so. Nothing else. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh - Ironically enough, modern C and C++ agree on this point :)

Comment: C was originally designed as a one pass compiler, so you need to forward declare items before using it.

Comment: The first code does not compile on my computer. It gives me "identifier not found" error. I use Visual Studio 2012 Express Edition for Windows Desktop. Btw, there should be a # in front of include but I don't think this is why the code compiles on your computer.

Comment: I have added the C tag back, as this question was asked as a comparison between C and C++. While the base of the question was wrong (c == c++), both the tags seem relevant here. let me know if anybody disagrees.

Comment: @daniel that must be a typo, anyway. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it is as much as wrong in C, as in C++.

Considering the question is based on the ***"assumption"*** that the code is valid from a C compiler point of view, let me elaborate that, as per the spec (`C11`), implicit declaration of functions is not allowed. Compile your code with strict conformance and (any conforming) compiler will produce the same error in C.

<kbd>**[See live example](https://ideone.com/WAqVjs)**</kbd>

Quoting `C11`, Foreword/p7, *"Major changes in the second edition included:"*

> - remove implicit function declaration

and the same exist in the `C99`, also.

---

Note: *On why it might have worked*

Pre `C99`, there was actually room for this code to be compiled successfully. In case of a missing function prototype, it was assumed that the function returns an `int` and accepts any number of parameters as input. That is now very much non-standard and compilers with legacy support may choose to allow such code to be compiled, but strictly speaking, a conforming compiler should refuse to do so.

Comment: A compiler compliant with C99 or later will reject the code.   Compilers that are older than 1999, or in "C89" modes (e.g. `gcc -stdc89`), generally do not claim compliance with C99.

Comment: @Peter Sometimes you need to enforce the "compliance" using options, it's not there by default...that's all i'm sayin'.

Answer (score 2):

> Why C++ Compiler Gives an Error?

Because you shall not call functions that have not been declared in C++.

> Is it not by default take int data type?

No. That used to be the case in another language, C. It is not the case in C++ (nor in C since later standard versions).

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you can't call an undeclared function. In C you can call a function without a forward declarator if the definition of the function returns an int. This is because of the old K&R function definition style. This is obsolete for ANSI-C, always declare a function with a prototype.

Comment: This is a tiny bit correct and mostly very wrong. When an undeclared function is encountered, the C compiler assumes a declaration (the linker will then complain if no implementation has been found). When the assumption is false, i.e. when a declaration or implementation is found later in the code,

Comment: and does not match with the assumption, a compiler error is given. This may be further influenced by your compiler version and compiler flags. By far the best advice is: don't do it; always declare up front.

Comment: @parvus, yes the C compiler assumes a declaration. This is a legacy of the old K&R C function style where a function declarator has no parameters and if the function returns an int, the declaration might well have been omitted.

Answer (score 1):

To complete the picture and in relation to the answer by [**Sourav Ghosh**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42804829/817643). Here's what the C++ standard has to say about the issue:

[[expr.call] p2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#2):

> [ Note: If a function or member function name is used, and name lookup does not find a declaration of that name, the program is ill-formed. No function is implicitly declared by such a call.  — end note ]

Couldn't get more explicit than that.