# change object from main in a function c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to get the values to rsaPrivate key, by calling a function.. because I have to use it other places in the main function, but I can't make it work. I have tried with and without pointer to rsaPrivate in the function.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    CryptoPP::RSA::PrivateKey rsaPrivate;
    getKeysFromPfx(&rsaPrivate);
}


void getKeysFromPfx(CryptoPP::RSA::PrivateKey *rsaPrivate) {
    try
    {
        rsaPrivate.BERDecodePrivateKey(queue, false /*paramsPresent*/, queue.MaxRetrievable());

        // BERDecodePrivateKey is a void function. Here's the only check
        // we have regarding the DER bytes consumed.
        assert(queue.IsEmpty());

        bool valid = *rsaPrivate.Validate(prng, 3);
        if (!valid)
        std::cerr << "RSA private key is not valid" << std::endl;
    catch (const Exception& ex)
    {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

}
```

the error is in the function where it says for rsaPrivate

> expression must have class type

Comment: Did You try to put the function *before* the *main* function?

Comment: You're missing at least one include from what you posted.

Comment: You should pass your `rsaPrivate` object by reference instead of a pointer though

Comment: What makes me suspicious: `CryptoPP::RSA::PrivateKey *rsaPrivate` but `rsaPrivate.BERDecodePrivateKey(...)`. I believe `.` must be `->` instead.

Comment: `rsaPrivate->something`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with missing forward declaration in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42804326/issue-with-missing-forward-declaration-in-c)

Comment: and add parens around your dereference: `(*rsaPrivate).Validate` since `.` has higher precedence than `*`.

Comment: @joH1 Simply put: remove the ```*``` and change the ```.``` to ```->```

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk yeah basically ^^

Comment: Please make a [mcve]

Comment: changing `.` to `->`works, thank you for quick answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the comments of this question, here is the solution.

Removing `*` from rsaPrivate and changing `.` to `->` when calling a function to rsaPrivate.